# A not so simple minimization?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, maxima-minima

$$h(x)=\Big({1\over x}\int_0^x (1-t)^{1/(1-x)}dt\Big)^{1-x},\quad 0<x<1$$ is some kind of a wicked mean of $1-t$. Anyhow the question is to show that it is first decreasing,  then increasing, and to find the minimum. Any thoughts?

Comment: Differentiation looks like the way to go.

Comment: $h(x)$ can be simplified to $\frac{\left(\frac{(1-x)^{\frac{1}{1-x}+2}+x-1}{x-2}\right)^{1-x}}{x}$.  Then plot that function and follow @DanielLittlewood 's advice.  From a plot it appears that the function is first increasing then decreasing to a minimum and then increases.

Comment: @JimB I'm not convinced that expression is correct - note the $\frac{1}{x}$ term is inside the brackets.  With the correct expression, the function does in fact decrease then increase.

Comment: @B.Mehta.  You are correct.  I mistakenly put it outside the brackets.  So the correct answer is $\left(\frac{(1-x)^{\frac{1}{1-x}+2}+x-1}{(x-2) x}\right)^{1-x}$.  And that also makes the given changes (first decreasing, then increasing) correct as the OP originally stated.

Comment: Not sure why it is decreasing and increasing. Can you support this with showing the derivatives?

Comment: Is not a plot of the function sufficient to be convincing about the decreasing followed by an increasing?